# jQuery - Make form elements disappear when value is selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This menu has four dropdown options:

```
<select name="menu-542" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="Maak uw keuze">Maak uw keuze</option>
<option value="Umrah Meivakantie">Umrah Meivakantie</option>
<option value="Umrah ramadan">Umrah ramadan</option>
<option value="Umrah individueel">Umrah individueel</option>
</select>
```

When "Umrah Meivakantie" is selected, I want two fields to disappear, namely:

```
<p id="vertrek-datum" class="umrah">Vertrekdatum <br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-465"><input type="text" name="date-465" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990864"> </span> </p>
```

and

```
<p id="eind-datum" class="umrah">Einddatum<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-466"><input type="text" name="date-466" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990865"> </span> </p>
```

Comment: Uh? `This menu has three dropdown options`, I don't see any menu, any dropdown or any option in your code. Only paragraphs with text. Please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do? (Run it below)

```js
var $umrah = $(".umrah");

$("select").on("change", function(){
  if( $(this).val()=='Umrah Meivakantie'){
    $umrah.hide();
  } else {
    $umrah.show();
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="menu-542" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="Maak uw keuze">Maak uw keuze</option>
  <option value="Umrah Meivakantie">Umrah Meivakantie</option>
  <option value="Umrah ramadan">Umrah ramadan</option>
  <option value="Umrah individueel">Umrah individueel</option>
</select> If you select "Umrah Meivakantie" it will hide two fields.
<br>
<p id="vertrek-datum" class="umrah">Vertrekdatum <br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-465"><input type="text" name="date-465" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990864"> </span> </p>

<p id="eind-datum" class="umrah">Einddatum<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-466"><input type="text" name="date-466" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990865"> </span> </p>

<p >Some other field<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-466"><input type="text" name="date-466" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990865"> </span> </p>

<p>Some other field<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-466"><input type="text" name="date-466" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990865"> </span> </p>
```

Comment: Yes this works, it was my syntax that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear :) Could you please then validate the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add value for `Umrah Meivakantie` and use the same value as class in the elements which you wants to hide like,

```
 <option value="Umrah Meivakantie">Umrah Meivakantie</option>
```

Add the umrah class to your `p-elements` like,

```
<p id="vertrek-datum" class="umrah">Vertrekdatum <br />
   [date date-465 date-format:mm/dd/yy] </p>
```

And onchange of your drop down element try the code like,

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="menu-542"]').on('change',function(){
       if(this.value=='Umrah Meivakantie'){
          $('#vertrek-datum,#eind-datum').hide();
       }
    });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('select[name="menu-542"]').on('change',function(){
       if(this.value=='Umrah Meivakantie'){
          $('#vertrek-datum,#eind-datum').hide();
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="menu-542" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="Maak uw keuze">Maak uw keuze</option>
<option value="Umrah Meivakantie">Umrah Meivakantie</option>
<option value="Umrah ramadan">Umrah ramadan</option>
<option value="Umrah individueel">Umrah individueel</option>
</select>

<p id="vertrek-datum" class="umrah">Vertrekdatum <br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-465"><input type="text" name="date-465" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990864"> </span> </p>
<p id="eind-datum" class="umrah">Einddatum<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-466"><input type="text" name="date-466" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date hasDatepicker" id="dp1424688990865"> </span> </p>
```

Comment: They already have values

<select name="menu-542" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">

<option value="Maak uw keuze">Maak uw keuze</option>

<option value="Umrah Meivakantie">Umrah Meivakantie</option><option value="Umrah ramadan">Umrah ramadan</option>

<option value="Umrah individueel">Umrah individueel</option>

</select>

Comment: Please check revised question and provide appropriate solution

Comment: But, Why my code is running see the snippet in my updated answer. Also make sure that you have already included a latest verion of jquery(At-least 1.7+).